# How can I convert video and stream it at same time use ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-conversion

linux vps , input video "phoenix.mkv" blueray quality

I want convert it

Video Quality : youtube 720p

Audio Quality : "MONO" , "libfaac" , "bitrate 112"

Output File : "output.mp4" or AnyFormat

*While converting i also want to watch / stream the output via VLC.*

How we can do this ??

*Already searching found some example for that*

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i input_file -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -x265-params crf=23 -strict experimental -f mpegts udp://192.168.2.10:1234
```

But the video output not looks like youtube 720 and output not saved to file.

**Thank you. :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1). Untested example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input -map 0 -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -c:a aac -f tee "[f=mpegts]udp://192.168.2.10:1234|[f=nut]pipe:" | vlc -
```

If your `ffmpeg` is not outdated you can use `-crf 23` instead of `-x265-params crf=23` and omit `-strict experimental`.